# Loading min.js files Generated by TypeScript with Require

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I have a full aplication working with Typescript and RequireJs, it is working perfectly. I have now download WebEssentials and it is generating the minified script files. WebEssentials generates separated *.min.js files with the same name as the original script file.

How can I tell RequireJs to load my minified files instead of my original script files ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use path config to override module paths. You can even fall back to non minified files:

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            'lib/jquery.min',
            'lib/jquery'
        ]
    }
});
```

There may be a more general way to use min files that I don't know about!

Comment: What's the performance cost of this? Your example favors production, but, just for an example, say I use `['scriptfile', 'scriptfile.min']`. `'scriptfile'` is in dev but only `'scriptfile.min'` is in production. How many times does RequireJS look for `'scriptfile'` in production, once or on every module requirement?

I assume there's a marginal bit of extra work simply because the property value is an array instead of a string.

Comment: In my informal testing, it tests these in order and is smart enough to understand that a 404 is a 404 (meaning to not look again). There is definitely a performance hit though if you are in dev but favored production, or vise versa.

Answer (score 9):

You can create a simple customized version of require which will conditionally append '.min.js' to all module file requests that would normally just receive the '.js' appendage. Consider the following:

```
    //Establish a new 'useMinified' boolean in your initial config.
    require.config({ useMinified: true });
```

Then, edit the require.js library file and modify the 'nameToUrl' function as below:

```
    //Join the path parts together, then figure out if baseUrl is needed.
url = syms.join('/');

    //new statement
var extension = config.useMinified ? '.min.js' : '.js';

    //customized statement
url += (ext || (/^data\:|\?/.test(url) || skipExt ? '' : extension));

url = (url.charAt(0) === '/' || url.match(/^[\w\+\.\-]+:/) ? '' : config.baseUrl) + url;
```

Comment: I just can't think of a reason why is this not implemented in requirejs yet!?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any magic to this. You have a few options though

1. Use the [RequireJS optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to generate min files for you. Very configurable.
2. Use the [`--out`](http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/typescript-compiler-commands/) compiler option to concatenate all your files into one and minify that
3. Create a script/batch file to copy your app somewhere else, rename all .min.js files to .js and overwrite the non-min'd ones. Or some other mix but you get the gist
4. Use the [paths config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths) like Steve mentioned. OK for small apps, less than ideal for large.

For the best performance you should look into the optimizer and determine if the single-script approach is the right decision or multiple smaller libraries is a better approach. I doubt that loading each .min.js file is the ideal solution for you.

Comment: Maybe the out parameter is the best solution. I have already tested and even if I minify and explicitly load the minified file in my main page, **Require** will still load the verbose, or no-minified, versions of my scripts. In this case, using one file with all scripts how can I tell Require to stop loading my scripts, since everything is already loaded ?

Comment: By the way the out paramter is not working Ok. No Script was generated in the --out parameter.

Comment: If you are using AMD `--out` won't work for you. You'll have to use the requirejs optimizer instead.