# How to include minified library version in RequireJS optimization

Tags: javascript, build, requirejs, r.js, optimization

My situation is as follows:

- My project based on RequireJS.
- I am using RequireJS Optimizer for to create a single JS file.
- Some of the module use a certain third party library as a dependency.
- The third party is NOT included in the optimized file (libName: empty
  in the build config).
- RequireJS is configured through var require = {} object which appears
  on EACH PAGE, right above the RequireJS. The object defines a path to
  the unminifed version of the library, among other things.

What i'd like to achieve:
Use the same config file in both development and production (the require={} object is included with  tag on each page). During development I'd like modules to use the UNMINIFIED version of the third party.However, after optimization occurs, i would like all the modules to use the minified version of that third party.

I did think of a solution in theory, but it seems a bit messy and Im hopeful cleaner solution exists:

To have the runtime config point to unminified version

```
var require = {
 paths:{
   'thirdParty':'lib/thirdParty'
}
}
```

Create a module which execute (lets call it "PathRewrite" Module):

```
requirejs.config({
 paths:{
   'thirdParty':'lib/thirdParty.min'
}
})
```

In runtime configuration, define path to "PathRewrite" as empty

```
var require = {
 paths:{
   'thirdParty':'lib/thirdParty',
   'PathRewrite':'empty'
}
}
```

In the build configuration file define a real Path to "PathRewrite" in order for it to be included in the "main" file (concatenated file after build).

Include "PathRewrite" as a dependency of a module which is executed first.

What I hope that will happen is that during dev, when optimized file is not used, PathRewrite is will not be used, hence the path to unminified third party in the runtime config will be used.
When the project is optimized, PathRewrite will be included and executed. According to RequireJS documentation, it is possible to run RequireJS configuration twice and the configuration will be appended/overwritten. PathRewrite execution will overwrite the path to "thirdParty" to minified, which will thus be used by all the modules.

Hopefully i've provided enough information. I'd be glad hear of other ways to get this done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This topic appears to have been explored a bit in this answer:

[Loading min.js files Generated by TypeScript with Require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323671/loading-min-js-files-generated-by-typescript-with-require)

Don't let the title discourage you.  Typescript is not the core issue of the question being answered there.  Unfortunately, the discussion reveals that the RequireJS optimizer may be the only way to get decent minification to work, as it seems incapable of selecting alternate paths properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use inbuilt RequireJs optimizer? You may just include [this option](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L91)

```
optimize : "uglify2"
```

and all your and third-party code will be minified after concatenation. In this case you don't need to use minified versions of third-party libraries.

Comment: One reason might be that the RequireJS optimizer is a build-time optimizer that does its own minification.  The poster's stated desire was to use the existing minified version of the 3rd party library.  Personally, I find the whole RequireJS approach to optimization to be very prescriptive and over-the-top, esp. when most projects already provide minified versions of their files.

Comment: @shahzbot I totally agree