# Load minified files generated by WebEssentials with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, bundling-and-minification

I used WebEssential tool to generate some minified version typescript files, so right now i have all the .min.js files.

Now I want to use that minified files version on the project, but they was never loaded.

I use to import modules like this:

```
import Controller1 = require('ctls/Controller1');
```

but it loads the normal .js file .

So how to change this behaviour and load the minified version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a require config entry.  See here:  http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

For example this might let you switch back and forth easily:

```
var minifiedPaths = { "Controller1": "ctls/Controller1.min" };
var devPaths = { "Controller1": "ctls/Controller1" };

require.config({
    paths: minifiedPaths
  });
```

And you could change your require call to `import Controller1 = require('Controller1');`

Note that TypeScript has issues with aliasing AMD modules like this, so you might need to keep the same name if you want to continue to get strong typing (or store a the d.ts file in the same location as the emitted library).

Comment: Actually this may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323671/loading-min-js-files-generated-by-typescript-with-require?rq=1 - the answer is the same regardless of the source of the minified file.